# How I can customize the table's header using the Datatable component?

Tags: datatable

At this moment I have a table that uses the DataTable component. The last column of the header is "Actions", but since the actions are obvious, I want to delete this text and move the "Show records" element of the table, to the same position where the text is now.

```
 Show XX records 
|--------------------------------------------------|
|  col1          | col2           | Actions        |
|---------------------------------------------------
|  col1 row1     | col2 row1      | Edit   Remove  |
|---------------------------------------------------
|  col1 row2     | col2 row2      | Edit   Remove  |
```

To make it looks like this:

```
|--------------------------------------------------|
|  col1          | col2           | Show XX records|
|---------------------------------------------------
|  col1 row1     | col2 row1      | Edit   Remove  |
|---------------------------------------------------
|  col1 row2     | col2 row2      | Edit   Remove  |
```

Can someone please help me?

Thanks so much

Comment: "Show XX records" is the dynamic count that datatable shows? you want to change its position?

Comment: yes, I want to change the position because the website design requires it.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is to use fnInfoCallback and change the header cell value in which you want to show info

```
"fnInfoCallback": function (oSettings, iStart, iEnd, iMax, iTotal, sPre) {

     $('#dtexample thead tr:first-child th:last-child').text('Showing ' + iStart + ' to ' + iEnd + 
' of '+iTotal );

  }
```